# can,t able to save hindi unicode character into mongodb for multiple fields

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, unicode, hindi, unicode-escapes

can,t able to save hindi unicode character into mongodb for multiple fields

```
  const WordsSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  word1:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
      language_override:"Hindi"
  },
  word2:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
      language_override:"Hindi"
  }
});
```

on setting language_override i able to save word1 but it don,t save word2

Code on angular side is ->

```
 <input class="form-control keyboardInput" id="Hindimeaning" [(ngModel)] ="word1" name="word1" placeholder="Meaning in Hindi 1" type="text">

<input class="form-control keyboardInput" id="Hindimeaning2" [(ngModel)] ="word2" name="word2" placeholder="Meaning in Hindi 2" type="text">
```

how can i save value for both inputs ....

Comment: mongo supports unicode, what error are you getting? can you post samples, expected output and errors if any?

Comment: actually i am able to save in mongoDB but only once i type that word  via suggestion given by input box .that will only pop once i typed that word already .... I want to add word in single stroke as i type them.  can you advice why this happening.